# process.waitFor() does not seem to return the right value

Tags: java, process

I am using the below code in my application ...

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "perl " + perlScript + " " + project + " " + fileName);
:
:
:
result = process.waitFor();
:
:
```

and this result gives the code 2 every time.....while running the application.

what could be the reason for the "reason code" ???

Thanks In Advance

Comment: The result of `waitFor` comes from `perl`, so this is actually unrelated to java. Retagging would be a good idea. You'll probably have to show us the perl script as well.

Comment: Is 2 the return code of Perl, or the perl script?
Does the perl script runs and terminates correctly?

Comment: we are using perl file as to validate the input file. 
Now, sometimes it gives return code as 0(means success) and sometimes it gives non zero(means unsuccess) for the same file.

Answer (score 2):

The perl script that you call is returning the value 2. You need to look at the perl script to determine what that value means--there is no generic way to know why a given program returns a given value.